# d3js line graph not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, invisible

I am working on creating a line graph and I am having a rather trivial issue. I am using d3js V4 and the specific code is as follows:

```
$(scope.container).append($('<svg id="svgimg" width="640" height="350" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></svg>'));
        var mainGroup = d3.select("#svgimg").append("g");
        d3.select("#svgimg").call(d3.zoom().on("zoom",function(){
            mainGroup.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.transform.x+","+d3.event.transform.y+") scale ("+d3.event.transform.k+")" );
        }));


        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%y");
        var svg = $("#svgimg"),
        margin = {top:20,right:20,bottom:20,left:20},
        width = +Number(svg.attr("width")) - margin.left -margin.right,
        height = +Number(svg.attr("height")) - margin.top-margin.bottom,
        g = mainGroup.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");
        //console.log(width);
        //console.log(height);
        var n = 2000;
        //  random = d3.randomNormal(0,.2),
        //  data = d3.range(n).map(random);

        var x =d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([new Date(2017,10,1),new Date(2017,10,31)])
            .range([0,width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,2000])
            .range([height,0]);
        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d,i){return x(parseTime(d.date));})
            .y(function(d,i){return y(Number(+d.distance));});

        g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id","clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height)
        g.append("g")
            .attr("class","axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform","translate(0,"+y(0)+")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        g.append("g")
            .attr("class","axis axis--y")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        g.append("g")
            //.attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
            .append("path")
            .datum(scope.data)
            .attr("d",line)
            .attr("class","linea");
        svg.innerHTML = svg.innerHTML;
```

Where scope is an object (this) with a number of components.

Specifically, the line for the line graph is not visible while the side and bottom scales are. Further, upon inspection, the path element has the some associated data and if only I could see it, could begin debugging.

Any info would be greatly appreciated

Edit: The scope.data object contains an array of objects with time,date,distance and stamp fields. The graph "d" attribute is showing an X range from -25000 -> 25000 with a Y value of 155. I should be seeing a horizontal line from left side to right side but this is not happening. Also, I believe the time parsing to be the major culprit. The time value has been temporarily modified to be equal to a UTC datetime string.

Edit: The time is a UTC datetime string similar to: 
    Tue Sep 19 2017 09:33:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)
With rows differing by +- 10 minutes

I am currently using the following code:
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse(d3.timeFormat.utc);

The complete array as from parsed json from browser

```
results
:
[{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 09:33:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"},…] 
0
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 09:33:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
1
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 09:23:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
2
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 09:13:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
3
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 09:03:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
4
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 08:53:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
5
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 08:43:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
6
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 08:33:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
7
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 08:23:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
8
:
{time: "Tue Sep 19 2017 08:13:42 GMT+1000 (AEST)", date: "11:00 AM", 
distance: "1000", stamp: "0"}
```

I appologise for not posting earlier however, I felt it was irrelevant as no edits in any way have brought the path element into view.

Comment: We don't have any idea of what `scope.data` is. Thus, I advise you to set up a [MCVE] somewhere.

Comment: scope.data is an array of objects with time,date,distance,stamp values. The d attribute contains values where x~=20000 and y ~= 200. It would appear the x value is not being parse properly (time handling, a common issue). I have modified the time field to equal to a UTC formatted timedate and am still recieving errors but it is definitely in the time handling.

Comment: Instead of describing the array, why don't you copy/paste a sample of it? The problem may be in the data, and we cannot see it just reading a description.

Comment: I have edited the original question to show a sample of the utc time

Comment: We cannot do anything with it. I said a sample of the **array**, at least a couple of objects. By that I mean the **entire** object. Well, I just give up, hope someone else can help you (by the way, if you already have dates, you don't need to parse them).

Answer (score 0):

@Gerado Furtado
   Thank you for your patience, you may have answered the question without realising it. The answer was to ensure the "`scope.data[].time`" attribute was parsed with "`new Date(scope.data[].time)`" and the solution has worked. Thank you again, Patrick.